# Random <a> displaying every time

Tags: php, html, random

Basically I have a gaming website, and I have added a div called othergames and it looks a little like this

```
<div id='othergames'>
    <h2>Other Games</h2>
       <div class="row">        <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/run2">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/run2.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">               <p>Run 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/effingworms">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/effingworms.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">                <p>Effing Worms</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/sportsheads">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/footballheads.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">              <p>Football Heads Championship</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/floodrunner2">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/floodrunner2.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">               <p>Flood Runner 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/happywheels">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/happywheels.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">                <p>Happy Wheels</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/mineblocks">
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/mineblocks.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">             <p>Mineblocks</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href='http://akgames.tk/games/bmxpark'>
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/bmxpark.png" width="60" height="60" alt=""/>               <p>BMX Park</p>
            </div>
        </a>
            <a href='http://akgames.tk/games/soccerballs2'>
            <div>
                <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/soccerballs2.png" width="60" height="60" alt=""/>              <p>Soccer Balls 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <p><br>to add: games change every time, padding on #row</p>
    </div>
        </p>
</div>
```

And what I'm trying to do is add a php script into the page like everytime someone goes on my page this:

```
<a href="http://akgames.tk/games/effingworms">
        <div>
            <img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/effingworms.png" width="60" height="60" alt="">                <p>Effing Worms</p>
        </div>
    </a>
```

changes to a different one..

Here's the page I'm working on http://akgames.tk/games/run2 at the bottom there's a other games list and yeah, everytime someone goes on it the  change to a different one.. please help

Comment: You should not use a `<div>` tag inside of an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you would store all your games in an array, like

```
$gamesArray = array('effingworms','run2');
```

etc, you could have a random game using PHP's rand

```
$maxRand = sizeof($gamesArray);
$selected = rand(0, $maxRand);
$result = $gamesArray[$selected];

<a href="http://akgames.tk/games/<?php echo $result; ?>"><img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/<?php echo $result; ?>.png"></a>
```

This is just an example, the script above is not tested for syntax errors, and can potentially generate the same number. Perhaps adding the results to a new array, and check each time that the generated value is unique would get rid of that. Hint hint.

**UPDATE**

To have a random for every game, something like this should work:

```
<?php


$gamesArray = array('effingworms','run2','game3','game4','game5','game6','game7','game8','game9','game10');
# To get the length of the array.
$maxRand = sizeof($gamesArray)-1;

# Initialize an array - to be used later.
$selectedArray = array();

# Items to be shown per page
$items = 7;

# Perform the action '$items' times
for($i=0;$i<$items;$i++) {

    # Generates a random number (which will reference one element in the array)
    $selected = rand(0, $maxRand);

       # This will disallow to have the same game twice
       if(!in_array($selected,$selectedArray)) {

           # If it is not present in the array yet, push it there
           array_push($selectedArray,$selected);
       } else { 

          # If it is already there, redo this step.
          $i--; }
}


for ($j = 0; $j<sizeof($selectedArray); $j++) {

    # List all selected items in HTML - this can be done easier using foreach
    $current = $selectedArray[$j];
    $result = $gamesArray[$current];

    ?>
    <a href="http://akgames.tk/games/<?php echo $result; ?>"><img src="http://akgames.tk/pictures/<?php echo $result; ?>.png"></a>
    <?php

}

?>
```

Comment: So yeah I did this but when I add more <a> tags it shows the same $result for all 6 of them, like look on akgames.tk/games/run2 it says sportheads on all. How can I do it so I can get a different one on each one?

Comment: @ttyredfg I have updated the answer, please take a look. You might have to correct typos, as I could not test this code.

Comment: Thank you man you helped me alot but I still have one more problem, whenever I go on the page (http://akgames.tk/games/run2) sometimes it shows me 2 of the games, sometimes 4 but I want it to show me all 7 if you know what I mean. So 7 games in the row that change. please help mate

Comment: @ttyredfg I have correct the plus ````$i++;```` and some bits and pieces. It looks OK now on mine (got to test it). Hope it'll work for you!